# Difference between addEventListener vs currentTarget

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between **addEventListener** and **currentTarget**? Can someone show me examples of how they are used differently? Thanks in advance

Comment: `addEventListener` is a method of an `EventSource` instance, `currentTarget` is a property of an `Event` instance - they are different stages of events in general - addeventlistener adds an event handler function to an event source, the handler function is called with an event as its one and only argument, this event has the currentTarget property

Answer (score 0):

sample code: ( do a click in any rectangle)

```js
document.getElementById('p-element').addEventListener('click', myfunction)

function myfunction(event)
  {
  console.clear()
  console.log( 'currentTarget:', event.currentTarget.tagName )
  console.log( 'target:', event.target.tagName, 'text:', event.target.textContent )
  }
```

```css
p   { border: 1px solid blue; padding: 1em;  cursor: pointer; } 
span   { border: 1px solid red; margin:1em;  }
```

```html
<p id="p-element">
  <span>span 1</span>
  <span>span 2</span>
  <span>span 3</span>
 </p>
```